# Column Visibility Based on each group SSRS 2008

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-grouping

![enter image description here][1]I am trying to achieve column visibility based on group name.  As you will see in my picture that I have displayed data based on my group name which are leakcheck, evac, pressure.  I have used code below in advanced mode in the column properties for column 2 (temp 1), when i used this code my column 2 disappeared for all the phase_type instead of just phase_type 2 and I have checked this forum for corrected answer but no luck.  I have tried just selecting that temp 1 column and using the same code below.  This makes my temp 1 column disappear but leaves a gap between (white space in between) column phase_type column and temp 2 column for evac name group.  Please help

```
    =iif(fields!Phase_Type.value = 2,true,false)
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8o0hi.jpg

Answer (score 0):

If you have a top level group that fits most grouping options then you can use something similar to ColumnVisible=Parameters!FilterGroupLevel.Value<4 and have a scheme for grouping here.

Comment: @Irb,  sorry I forgot to post the link.  I have posted the link please let me know what you think and your suggestions. Thanks

Comment: The best way I have found to hide columns is to select the column header in the matrix and left click and set your condition in the Column Visiblity panel.